# Using 2 stacks to create a Queue

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

```
class Queue2Stacks(object):

    def __init__(self):

        # Two Stacks
        self.instack = []
        self.outstack = []

    def enqueue(self,element):

        # Add an enqueue with the "IN" stack
        self.instack.append(element)

    def dequeue(self):
        if not self.outstack:
            while self.instack:
                # Add the elements to the outstack to reverse the order when called
                self.outstack.append(self.instack.pop())
        return self.outstack.pop()
```

Can someone please help me understand this question? I don't really understand how does the if not self.outstack work here. I thought the self.outstack start with an empty list, why would it triggers this statement? I also don't understand the while self.instack here, self.instack is a list that we appended from enqueue function right? What would break this while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` condition you refer to:

```
if not self.outstack:
```

...means "if outstack is empty". This is necessary, because the intended action is to pop a value from that stack (see `return` statement). Now if there is nothing there, we cannot just raise an exception "sorry, nothing there any more", as there might still be values in the other stack : `instack`. So in that case we need to return a value from *that* stack: the value we need to return is at the *bottom* of `instack`. So we will need to pop *all* values from that stack, and append them to `outstack`, which effectively will put them in reverse order: the value that was at the bottom of `instack`, will end up at the top of `outstack`, and that is exactly what we want, because we will pop that element as return value.

The `while` condition is saying: "while there are still values in `instack`". This is needed, because we want *all* values to be popped from that stack.

Answer (score 0):

Better understanding of the loop structures may help with this piece of code. 
Here's a resource: http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/conditionals.html

```
  if not (apples >= 5): 
     print("You have a few apples only.")
```

is similar to that of:

```
  if (apples <= 5):
     print("You have a few apples only.")
```

the logic gate is a little more deeper with the understanding of "not" as in not a "!" operator. Hope that helps with the understanding of your code.